# Can you create a table with categories and what is classified under each one from a data frame

Tags: r, datatable, pivot

is there a way to change a table like this A to B:

TABLE A - made up data

| CAT | Type |
| --- | --- |
| home | house |
| holiday | caravan |
| holiday | hotel |
| home | bungalow |

TABLE B - change to:

| Home | Holiday |
| --- | --- |
| House | caravan |
| bungalow | hotel |

I am new to r and have tried pivots and list but not sure if I am doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
> with(df, list2DF(split(Type, CAT)))
  holiday     home
1 caravan    house
2   hotel bungalow
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(CAT = c("home", "holiday", "holiday", "home"),
    Type = c("house", "caravan", "hotel", "bungalow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```